# Create Index based off Column

Tags: r, merge, grouping, data-manipulation

I have two data sets:

```
# 1.
user_id  users    frequency
1        1        3
2        1        1
3        1        1

# 2.
user_id  sum      unique
1        2        1
2        0        0
3        1        1
```

I want to merge on `user_id` but have index based on unit1 in an ordinal fashion so the output would look like, leaving `user_id` out of the picture:

```
# 3.
frequency users sum    unique
3         1     2      1
1         2     1      1
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Also, in terms of learning how to do these types of manipulations, is their a name for this type of manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)         # this step was to make it a data.table, if its a data.frame
setDT(df1)

# logic is : first merge both df's, then group by "frequency" columns
df[df1][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(frequency), .SDcols = c("sum", "unique", "users")]
#   frequency sum unique users
#1:         3   2      1     1
#2:         1   1      1     2
```

Comment: @StuRichards does it answer your real data? did i miss anything?

Comment: is df referencing data set 1/df1 referencing data set 2?

Comment: Thanks for your help here Joel

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`.  We can do an `inner_join` between the two datasets, grouped by 'frequency', we get the `sum` of the variables within `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2) %>%
       group_by(frequency) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(sum), sum, unique, users)
#    frequency   sum unique users
#      <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#1         1     1      1     2
#2         3     2      1     1
```

---

Or using `base R`, we `merge` the datasets and do an `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~frequency, merge(df1, df2)[-1], FUN = sum)
#    frequency users sum unique
#1         1     2   1      1
#2         3     1   2      1
```